# How can I trick system.windows.forms.application.startuppath into returning a different directory?

Tags: c#, reflection, directory

I'm trying to reflect into an installed app. It loads files from it's local folder. I had initially assumed just using `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory` would work, unfortunately, some of the code in the assembly I'm reflecting into uses `system.windows.forms.application.startuppath` which ignores the current working directory and loads the dir the running assembly (my code) started from. While I'm aware that what I am asking for is black magic, is there some way to trick that constant into temporarily thinking it's not where my actual app is starting?

Alternatively, as I type this, I'm thinking it might be an x-y problem, can someone think of a better solution than this?

Comment: Acording to the reference source the property has backing field, you should be able to change its value using reflection.

Comment: @thehennyy I hadn't considered using reflection on system assemblies. That sounds..... Well, not fun, but doable.

Comment: I don't think you can do it directly, what left for you is reflection.

Comment: what is the line of code that you want to apply this magic to? may be there is an alternative

Comment: Maybe make it where your program starts a shell program from the app directory then reflects into your main app to do the work, unless you can't put files in the app's directory.  I guess that is not temporary, but I would just account for it in your own application by having a global static for real app directory.

Comment: @Carter I don't think I could do that, but it gives me an idea. I could create a seperate exe that launches from the app's directory and acts communicates with my primary app to do reflected tasks.

Comment: Yea apples and oranges that was my basic premise just have like a proxy within the apps location.